# How do I set the language for datetimepicker?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, datetimepicker

Is there any property to set the language for datetimepicker?

When displaying the calendar, that is - if I want the week days to be displayed in Spanish, for example...

Comment: Looks like the DateTimePicker will always use the OS culture, not the one of your app. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/889834/the-datetimepicker-and-monthcalendar-control-do-not-reflect-the-curren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the culture, which contains weekdays names among other things,  on a single control like the DateTimePicker, but at thread level.

Comment: OK - thanks! Then I know it isn´t possible for the datetimepicker itself :-)

Comment: I just checked; Changing the culture will use the new culture's date format, but at least on Win7, the popup still uses the OS user culture's strings.

Comment: @OregonGhost Looks like the DateTimePicker will always use the OS culture, not the one of your app. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/889834/the-datetimepicker-and-monthcalendar-control-do-not-reflect-the-curren

Answer (score 5):

You can change culture for thread:

```
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES");
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

Comment: @colmde Looks like the DateTimePicker will always use the OS culture, not the one of your app. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/889834/the-datetimepicker-and-monthcalendar-control-do-not-reflect-the-curren