# Change the Language of DateTimePicker Control

Tags: c#, .net

I want to change the language of `DateTimePicker` control. For that i changed the region language on DropDown event of `DateTimePicker` control, but it does not effect on DateTimePicker control. Code is

```
private void dtpDate_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new   System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
}
```

I also tried after this

```
dtpDate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
string[] formats = dtpDate.Value.GetDateTimeFormats(Application.CurrentCulture);
dtpDate.CustomFormat = formats[0];
```

but still having problem :-(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148234/how-do-i-set-the-language-for-datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

Сhange the `Culture` of your `Thread`:

```
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("xx-XX");
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

Comment: By default, that only works if you do it at the start of your program, before all the resources are cached.

Comment: Thanks MikroDel, but calender still in english :-(

Comment: @RizwanAnsari - have you change .CultureInfo("xx-XX") to what you need? ) And started your application again..

Comment: new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"). 
 

 current regional lenguage of my system is German and let's want to change in Englisg i.e "en-GB" still calender of datetimepicker is in Gweman when i drop down the control.